# Exclude Service Groups and outside members in Azure AD Dynamic Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory

Would like to create a dynamic group in Azure AD that has the following criteria:

Only include individual user accounts (no service accounts) who are actually employees of our company.

I think there should be a way to accomplish the first criteria, but a bit unsure about the second.

Also would be great if the group could be alphabetical.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The rule or rules will depend on how you have your employee users organized. Only users can be assigned dynamically.

Below you will find some samples:

###### If employees are all members (not guests):

`(user.userType -eq "member")`

###### If employees are all members (not guests) who have the Exchange Online (Plan 2) service plan assigned and enabled:

`(user.userType -eq "member") and (user.assignedPlans -any (assignedPlan.servicePlanId -eq "efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0" -and assignedPlan.capabilityStatus -eq "Enabled"))`

Etc.

For more information, please take a look to [Dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership)